# Jquery to detect mobile and show code based upn conditions

Tags: jquery

I am trying to run a code in a single page which is a html page that if the website is opening in mobile or desktop, i found this tutorial but not sure how to use it

http://magentohostsolution.com/3-ways-detect-mobile-device-jquery/

```
<canvas id="low-poly"></canvas>

  <!-- YOUTUBE PLAYER -->
  <div id="video" data-video="ClIBmBT9clU" data-mute="true"></div>
  <!-- /YOUTUBE PLAYER -->
```

use youtube if it is not mobile and ipad or tablet, other than that use it

I am really a noob in programming, just started

Comment: Please add the code you are trying to use and your results from it

Comment: `if (isMobile) { document.write('<div id="video" data-video="ClIBmBT9clU" data-mute="true"></div>'); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```js
if (!(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent))) { //check if mobile and invert result
  console.warn("Desktop detected");
  $("#youtube").html(`<div id="video" data-video="ClIBmBT9clU" data-mute="true"></div>`); //append player
}
```

```css
strong.warning {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="youtube">
  <strong class="warning">Please use desktop</strong>
</div>
```

Or like this:

```js
const isMobile = (function isMobile() {
  try{ document.createEvent("TouchEvent"); return true; }
  catch(e){ return false; }
})(); //create mobile-detection function and use it
if (!isMobile) { //check if mobile and invert result
  console.warn("Desktop detected");
  $("#youtube").html(`<div id="video" data-video="ClIBmBT9clU" data-mute="true"></div>`); //append player
}
```

```css
strong.warning {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="youtube">
  <strong class="warning">Please use desktop</strong>
</div>
```

Also desktop browser do not have orientation property, so you can also use this (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser/14301832#14301832)):

```
const isMobile = typeof window.orientation !== "undefined";
```